# Why can't I trade TF2 items to a second account?

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2

I've played TF2 for 4 years now. My old Steam Account got to slow to operate, so I made a new one.

I got a starter crate for each class to start me off, because I heard in order to trade, you must be a pay-to-play player. So I went to my old computer, started Steam, and befriended my new account so I could trade easily without having to join a server.

- I got onto TF2 on my new account and waited for my old computer to load the game.
- I went to items -> Trade -> Friends and clicked my old account.

It immediately said "waiting for a response from jsequi4" or something. 30...29... and then it stopped saying that my account may be unavailable to trade. I question this. I worked hard for all my strange items and I wish to trade them to my new account. Why is this happening?

Comment: How does a steam account become too slow to operate? That doesn't make any sense...

Comment: Trading from the game itself can be buggy at times. I wonder if that's what happened to you.

Answer (score 4):

Just log into your old steam account on your new computer. There's nothing linking that steam account to only that computer.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [ballsy26's](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/149096/ballsy26) answer, as long as there isn't any items on your new account that you would like, as all you have to do is log on to your old account from your new computer (assuming you still know your username and password)

To try and answer your question as to why it will not trade, here could be a few reasons why:

1. Does the old account have [Steam Guard](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=4020-ALZM-5519#what) enabled? Steam Guard must be enabled for at least 15 days before trading is allowed. This was required for trading as of December 12, 2012.
2. Have you recently changed the e-mail and/or password of your old account? This will cause that account to be untradeable for the next 5 days.
3. Has your old account ever been trade banned or restricted? This will result in the account no longer being allowed to trade.

More information can be found here: https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Trading